# Spring Social and Spring Security using XML configuration

Tags: java, spring-social

I'm trying to introduce Spring Social into an exising web-application that Spring Security. The existing web-app uses XML configuration, ie:

```
<security:http  
    disable-url-rewriting="true"
    use-expressions="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    ...
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/w/configuration/**"
        access="hasRole ('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    ...
    <form-login
        login-page="/w/welcome"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/w/welcome"/>
</security:http>
```

How do I add the SpringSocialConfigurer() into the configuration? All the documentation on Spring Social uses Java-based configuration which I want to avoid, eg:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/authenticate")
            .failureUrl("/signin?param.error=bad_credentials")
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}
```

What is the XML equivalent of the apply() method?

Answer (score 5):

After spending some time reviewing the code for SpringSocialConfigurer, here are the *somewhat* equivalent XML configuration for what it does:

```
<security:http  
    disable-url-rewriting="true"
    use-expressions="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    ...
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/w/configuration/**"
        access="hasRole ('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    ...
    <form-login
        login-page="/w/welcome"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/w/welcome"/>

    <!-- Add a custom filter to handle Social media logins -->
    <custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="socialAuthFilter"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager
    id="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <!-- Social Media sites as authentication provider -->
    <authentication-provider ref="socialAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!--
   Define the framework required for using Social Media sites
   as Authentication Providers.
 -->
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${social.facebook.appId}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${social.facebook.appSecret}" />                
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="socialUsersConxRepo"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.mem.InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
</bean>
<bean id="socialUserIdSource"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource"/>
<bean id="socialAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="socialUserIdSource"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="socialUsersConxRepo"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
</bean>
<bean id="socialAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="socialUsersConxRepo"/>

    <!-- application defined @Service -->
    <constructor-arg ref="socialGamerManager"/>
</bean>
```

The application programmer is expected to write their own "socialGamerManager" bean which must implement `org.springframework.social.security.SocialUserDetailsService`. The "socialUsersConxRepo" bean may be changed to use a JDBC implementation.